# All lines together form a circle

Tags: html, css

I want all these seven lines will be arranged in such a way that they form a circular design.As in background a demo circle is designed, all seven line are croped in such a way that they exactly touch the circle's border.Here,seven classes are coded having seven different colors.At final stage,Only all these seven lines should be visible in circular format.

```css
.div7 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 10px;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
}

.div6 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 10px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.div1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 10px;
  background: green;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.div2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 10px;
  background: yellow;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.div3 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 10px;
  background: pink;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.div4 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 10px;
  background: cyan;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.div5 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 10px;
  background: gray;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div style="border:1px solid;border-radius:50%;width:100px;">

  <div class="div7"></div>
  <div class="div6"></div>
  <div class="div1"></div>
  <div class="div2"></div>
  <div class="div3"></div>
  <div class="div4"></div>
  <div class="div5"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might surprise you how easy this is.

All you have to do is to add `overflow: hidden;` to your parent div:

```css
.circle {
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.div1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 10px;
  background: green;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.div2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 10px;
  background: yellow;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.div3 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 10px;
  background: pink;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.div4 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 10px;
  background: cyan;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.div5 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 10px;
  background: gray;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.div6 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 10px;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 5px;
}

.div7 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 10px;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">

  <div class="div7"></div>
  <div class="div6"></div>
  <div class="div1"></div>
  <div class="div2"></div>
  <div class="div3"></div>
  <div class="div4"></div>
  <div class="div5"></div>

</div>
```